# Compiler error and String class not recognizing methods

Tags: c++, class, compilation

I made my own string class and for some reason, the intellisense is not picking up methods that I clearly defined and am trying to use.  Not only is the intellisense not picking up these methods, but I get a build error when I try to compile.

The only method that the intellisense is picking up is `Display()`. `Test()` and `GetString()` are no where to be found in the `String` class and say `There is no member Test() and no member GetString` when I try to compile.

**string.cpp**

```
#include "String.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

String::String() :m_SingleChar('\0'), m_CString(nullptr)
{ }

String::String(char Character) : m_SingleChar(Character)
{ }

String::String(char * CharacterString)
{
    if (CharacterString != nullptr)
    {
        m_CString = new char [strlen(CharacterString) + 1];
        strcpy (m_CString, CharacterString);
    }
}

String::~String()
{
    delete [] m_CString;
}

String::String(const String & copy) : m_SingleChar(copy.m_SingleChar)
{
    if (copy.m_CString != nullptr)
    {
        m_CString = new char [strlen(copy.m_CString) + 1];
        strcpy (m_CString, copy.m_CString);
    }
}

String & String::operator = (const String & rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        delete [] m_CString;
        if(rhs.m_CString == nullptr)
            m_CString = nullptr;
        else
        {
            m_CString = new char[strlen(rhs.m_CString) + 1];
            strcpy (m_CString, rhs.m_CString);
        }
        m_SingleChar = rhs.m_SingleChar;
    }
    return *this;
}

char * String::GetString(String m_CString)
{
    char * Cstring = m_CString.m_CString;
    return Cstring;
}

void String::Test()
{
}

void String::Display()
{
    cout << "Single character: " << m_SingleChar << endl;
    cout << "C String:  " << m_CString << endl;
}
```

**string.h**

```
#ifndef STRING_H
#define STRING_H


class String
{
public:
    String();
    String(char Character);
    String(char * CharacterString);
    ~String();
    String(const String & copy);
    String & operator = (const String & rhs);
    char * GetString (String CString);
    void Test();
    void Display();

private:
    char m_SingleChar;
    char * m_CString;
};

#endif
```

The exact error occurs at this line with the error message:

```
Error   1   error C2039: 'Test' : is not a member of 'String'       
23  1   Potion Class     2
```

...

```
int * Potion::GetMoney (int * coins)
{
    String something;
    something.Test();  //Error occurs here

    return coins;
}
```

Does anyone know why the class won't compile?

Does anyone know why the compiler is saying `void Test()` and `char * GetString` is not recognizing them as members of my string class??

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the error and the exact error from it.

Comment: Just added the exact error message and the line that it breaks @chris.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get an error about no C string functions because you forgot to include `<cstring>`, but then it compiles cleanly. And that's definitely not an SSCCE. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6ba596a1cf473aa

Comment: Thanks chris.  Yeah, I made a brand new string class, copy and pasted everything and it works now.  So weird.  :(

Comment: seem to be linker problem can you show us the all files in the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled both string.h & string.cpp on Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 & its not giving me error that you specified.

I replaced `nullptr` with `NULL` as I am not using C++11. Also, by replacing `strcpy` with `strcpy_s` & it compiled.